# I am trying to update my mySQL database, however when I try update more than one column an error occurs

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to edit/update details that have been entered into a form. When I try update the address by itself, it works. However when I try update more than one column, it does not. I am assuming there is an issue with the below code as it works with one entity but not more than one.

```
Update register set (address, contact) = concat('"+address+"', '"+mob+"');
```

This is the java code. This is error showing, the jsp shows as a blank page

```
try{

          String session_id =null;
    HttpSession session1=request.getSession(false); 


    if(session1!=null){  
    session_id=(String)session1.getAttribute("name");  

    }

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String mob = request.getParameter("contact");

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alt", "root", "");


      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      stmt.execute("Update register set (address, contact) = concat('"+address+"', '"+mob+"') where uid='"+session_id+"'");
      out.println("registration success");
      response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

    }catch(Exception e){

    }


    %>
```

Comment: You need to use `UPDATE <table> SET <column1> = <value1>, <columns2> = <value2>`

Comment: It is showing a blank page because you are swallowing/ignoring the exception. Never do that, at minimum log it or print it to the error out (eg `e.printStackTrace()`). In any case, your query is wrong; look at the correct syntax in the MySQL documentation. In addition do not ever concatenate values into a query string. It is unsafe and makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Please learn about prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this syntax of update:

```
    update register set
    address = concat('"+address+"', '"+mob+"'),
    contact = concat('"+address+"', '"+mob+"')
    where uid='"+session_id+"'");
```

Comment: where condition is missing

Comment: then added it in your answer